# So i was making a script for my sheets document and it doesnt update my file. why? any help is much appriciated. ty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

so this is the code im using..

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Kartell Buchhaltung Rob" && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,5).getValue()== ""){
    var currDate = new Date();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,5).setValue(currDate);
  }

}
```

it should change my fifth column to a date if its empty.. but it doesnt.. the cell is formated to show date.. im at a loss here..

Comment: There are only two conditions in your `if` statement. One of those is evaluated as false. Change your sheet name to something simpler like `s1`

Comment: i found the issue, the table needed to be named the same as the sheet.. its working as expected now.. ty